# How to browse definition of a method in a .dll when reading code the same way when debugging that code?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, definition

When reading codes, I often run into a metadata file like the marked-red as in the below snapshot.

For the same code, when debugging, Visual Studio IDE will ask to browse for the definition code of the `.dll` file. I browse to the source of that `dll` and can continue to debug with that pointed-out source.

What I need is: When browing the code (NOT when debugging), I am able to browse/be-asked-to-choose the source of that `metadata` dll source code when call `Go to definition` and/or `Pressing F12` - I don't want to paintfully start a debug to be able to see the code of the dll.

I don't know how to do that or is it possible. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Just add the project that created that DLL to your solution.

Comment: @Passant My source of that DLL is organized to be stored in a separate solution and I don't want to re-add them in the project instead of telling the IDE where the source is - which is already available when debug. Why not available when browse code only? Thanks you Passant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will do this whenever it does not have access to the debug information for an assembly.

When you build programs, typically you do a DEBUG build in dev environments, with a RELEASE build performed for production/test environments. However, it is possible that you use referenced assemblies that were compiled without debug information.

> I'm not exactly sure what you're asking:

If you want to avoid this happening, then make sure, when you debug that all assemblies are built in debug mode.

If you WANT this to occur, then build the required assembly in RELEASE mode.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my question clear enough. I've updated it. Please have a look again. I want it occur but occur when browsing code NOT when debugging code. Hope to continue to learn from your answer BonyT.